# Is it possible to hide android navigation bar from when playing video in full screen mode in browser?

Tags: javascript

I have a website with a `video.js` player. When I watch a video in a fullscreen mode, I can still see the android navbar.

Screenshot
[image]

I tried to implement my own script to call fullScreen on the HTML5  tag, but it didn't help. It goes full screen, but I can still see the navbar.

```
function toggleFullScreen(docEl) {
  var doc = window.document;
  var requestFullScreen = docEl.requestFullscreen || docEl.mozRequestFullScreen || docEl.webkitRequestFullScreen || docEl.msRequestFullscreen;
  var cancelFullScreen = doc.exitFullscreen || doc.mozCancelFullScreen || doc.webkitExitFullscreen || doc.msExitFullscreen;

  if (!doc.fullscreenElement && !doc.mozFullScreenElement && !doc.webkitFullscreenElement && !doc.msFullscreenElement) {
    requestFullScreen.call(docEl);
  }
  else {
    cancelFullScreen.call(doc);
  }
}
```

I thought that using fullscreen on  tag would help, but it doesn't. What else can I do?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @HTMHell Unfortunately, no

Comment: I did eventually. You should use the latest videojs version